# Azure AD authentication giving error for signing in admin of database after azure deployment of the web app

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory

[Link to SSMS snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LUJs.png)I have created a web app in .NET MVC and added azure ad authentication to it. On running it on local host everything is working very correct. But when I deploy the application on azure web app and put that URL in redirect URI its throwing error as:

Login failed for user 'admin@poc'.

As a deployment dependency we need to create a database on Azure, I have done that too and placed the connection string in the web config also. The user id and passwords are correct as able to connect to database using same credentials in management studio.

Below is the connection string:

Below is the stack trace:

[SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'admin@poc'.]
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager) +947
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +342
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +38
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +514
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +91
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +438
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +79 System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +201
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +156 System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +22
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +92 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +219
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +101
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.<>c.b__13_0(DbConnection t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext c) +12
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +72
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +424
System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass60_0.b__0() +426
System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.b__0() +10
System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +189 System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation) +78 System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +175
System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +552 System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.CreateDatabaseFromScript(Nullable`1 commandTimeout, DbConnection sqlConnection, String createDatabaseScript) +90
System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection) +173 System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection) +76
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateDatabase() +134
System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DatabaseCreator.Create(DbConnection connection) +119
System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase) +142
System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration) +78
System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase(InternalContext internalContext, Func`3 createMigrator, ObjectContext objectContext) +89 System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CreateDatabase(ObjectContext objectContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState) +116 System.Data.Entity.Database.Create(DatabaseExistenceState existenceState) +218 System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context) +138
System.Data.Entity.Internal.<>c__DisplayClass66_0`1.<CreateInitializationAction>b__0() +76 System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +60 System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization() +372 System.Data.Entity.Internal.<>c.<InitializeDatabase>b__58_0(InternalContext c) +9 System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input) +129
System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action) +196 System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase() +86 System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize() +30 System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +16 System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +53
System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() +15 System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider() +38
System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate) +85
selftrial.Models.ADALTokenCache..ctor(String signedInUserId) in C:\Users\ShubhendraShukla\source\repos\selftrial\selftrial\Models\AdalTokenCache.cs:26
selftrial.Startup.b__7_0(AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification context) in C:\Users\ShubhendraShukla\source\repos\selftrial\selftrial\App_Start\Startup.Auth.cs:54
Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.d__9.MoveNext() +4047
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +27
Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.d__9.MoveNext() +5436
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +102
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +64
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.d__31.MoveNext() +452
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +102
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +64
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.d__5.MoveNext() +217
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +102
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +64
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.d__7.MoveNext() +179
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +102
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +64
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.d__5.MoveNext() +519
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +102
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +64
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.d__7.MoveNext() +179
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +102
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +64
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.d__12.MoveNext() +180
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult ar) +69
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.EndFinalWork(IAsyncResult ar) +64
System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +429
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +50
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +163

Comment: First get running using SSMS under same conditions.You have to run SSMS from same machine as your server code and when you login on SSMS use Username and Password in login window (not Window Credential).When you run an application from inside Visual Studio you not running with Admin credentials unless you right click the VS shortcut and select Run As Admin.I'm suspecting you are working with window credentials (connection string has Integrated Security = True) and not when you use a Username/Password.Roles on Server may not accept Username/Password.  Or you are not using same database.

Comment: @jdweng I connected to SSMS using same sql authentication. So do you suggest to change something in config

Comment: The connection string has to be the same as the SSMS.  The SSMS login window has a Server Name, An Instance, and Credentials which can be windows (in connection string Integrated Security = True) or Username/Password.  So fixing connection string should solve issue.  The server may have more than one database so you have to make sure you are using the correct database.

Comment: Check the snapshot to the SSMS, and it has only one db. Below is the URL to the image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LUJs.png @jdweng

Comment: If SSMS is working from same machine as c# application should also work without any other changes.  The properties of the connection (c# connection string and SSMS login windows) have to also be the same.  When running from VS you are not automatically running As Admin unless you start VS from right click shortcut and select Run As Admin.  There is nothing wrong with your firewall and would ignore the answer below.

Comment: Also in console I am getting this error 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

selftrial20201120124240.azurewebsites.net/:1

Comment: Is error occurring when you are making a connection or when performing a query?  Can you run same query from SSMS?  I think the connection completed and something is corrupted in the query.  I assume you checked the connection string and you are connecting to same server.  I would like to see the connection string to see what options you are using.  Does connection string contain "AttachDB".  If the database is already attached to the server you should not attach again in connection string.

Comment: <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Server=tcp:selftrialdbserver.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=selftrial_db;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=admin@trial@selftrialdbserver;Password={********};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 

This is the conn string

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have not configured the SQL firewall to allow connections from Azure resources. In the Azure Portal, find the Azure SQL Database and click "Set server firewall":

[image]

Ensure that the slider for "Allow Azure services(..)" is set to "Yes".

[image]